# Нужна помощь в разборке php кода

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, вот столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу разобраться что и как работает в данном куске кода:

```
          <div>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
            <ul>
              <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
              <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
              <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
              <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?>
                </a>
              </li>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
```

Он отвечает за вывод суб категорий на сайте в виде:

- Компьютеры (35)
- Мобыльные телефоны (10)

Необходимо убрать вот эти цифры количества товаров рядом с суб категориями. Я не смог понять где именно они находятся и как от них избавится, и можно ли это сделать путём редактирования вышевыложенного Кода. В php я не очень силён поэтому прошу очень вашей помощи.

```
          <div>
            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
            <ul>
              <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
              <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
              <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
```

И по возможности распишите пожалуйста что это за переменные задаются... и для чего. Это ведь цикл, и переменные для него. 
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в админке в настройках это отключается. а если не хочешь в настройках, то топаешь в catalog->controller->product->category.php (примерно 143 строка), находишь вот такой участок кода

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $product_total . ')' : ''),
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
            );
```

и меняешь его на

```
$this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'],
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
            );
```

Вот тут в админке меняется. Надеюсь найдешь.

http://s002.radikal.ru/i198/1308/5f/1dd12283646c.jpg

чето изображение не вставляется...

Comment: неслабая телепатия ;)

Comment: Да-да! Мне тоже стало интересно, о чем здесь речь, и как автор дал сей ответ))

Comment: @Johny, это Опенкарт, неплохая и гибкая кстати система =)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Да у меня движок OpenCart. А не подскажешь где именно в админке это отключить?

Comment: @KeH192 лучше в следующий раз более подробно что да как :) т.е. явно указывать самописное или какойто движок, так будет всем проще :)

Comment: @KeH192, дополнил ответ

Comment: Благодарю тебя, очень сильно помог!